# Drop down menu with array, define value of each option

Tags: javascript, html, dropdown

Hello there Stackoverflow!

Today I tried making a `drop-down menu` with an `array`. It did work, but the problem that has taken place after this, is to define the `values` printed by the `array`.

As of now, this is the code regarding the `drop-down menu`.

**HTML**

```
<select id="selectDestinasjon">
    <option>Velg ett sted</option>
</select>
```

**Javascript**

```
var select = document.getElementById("selectDestinasjon");
var options = ["Konsberg", "Trysil", "Beitostølen"];
for (var i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
  var opt = options[i];
  var el = document.createElement("option");
  el.textContent = opt;
  el.value = opt;
  select.appendChild(el);
}
```

But I want to give each option a value, that I can later impliment into a calculator, because I want to make a booking service where each of these options has different value and the calculator retrieve info from current selected option, setting a price depending on selected option.

If anything seem unclear or too little detailed, please ask and I'll do my best to explain.

**JSFIDDLE**
https://jsfiddle.net/a3pe6zcu/

Comment: you code seems to be working. each option DOES have a value

Comment: I mean a price specified value. That each individual place got a dollar price, but implimented through a array

Comment: Use an object, or an array with keys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this? I have updated your data to hold the price and the name of the place. Now the select has the text as the place and the price as the value. [**Updated fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/a3pe6zcu/1/)

```
var select = document.getElementById("selectDestinasjon");
var options = [{"place": "Konsberg","price":"$20"}, {"place":"Trysil","price":"$30"}, {"place":"Beitostølen","price":"$40"}];
for(var i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
var opt = options[i];
var el = document.createElement("option");
el.textContent = opt.place;
el.value = opt.price;
select.appendChild(el);
}
```

Comment: I think this is very close to exactly what I am aming for, but I just have to do some asking to understand the code(hence my name). The different values you have set like, value = opt.price, is that what ill use to calculate selected price?

Comment: Sure not a problem. The options array has elements which are hashes ({'name':'value'} pairs). Each element corresponds to data (place, price)  for particular place. The for loop you had is exactly the same as what I have. But within the for loop, you were getting the names of the places but my `opt` is going to be the hash object. To access hash, am using `opt.place` and `opt.price`. Hope that makes sense. The rest is what you already had. Only these 3 lines have been changed.

Comment: I think I understand, but just incase. IF you got extra time on your hands, could you make an example targeting price, just to see how to do it?

Comment: You should use `onChange` on the select and get the value of the select in the callback function. I suggest you use a library like `jQuery` where you can do such stuff easily. Something like this

`$('#selectDestinasjon').on('change',function() {
    var target_price = $(this).val();
    alert(target_price)
});`

Please accept this answer if it helped you and upvote. thanks!

Comment: Done, too little rep to upvote, but accepted. I understand if you dont want to do this, but could you do a updated fiddle with an example?

Comment: No problem. I just updated the fiddle I have in the answer. Just change the dropdown option and see the magic! Notice that I have added jquery.min.js as requirement in the jsfiddle (External resources). You will need this in your code as well.

Comment: Thank you so much, could I possibly ask you in the future if I wonder about anything regarding this? Got alot remaning on my calculator and want to finish it without opening too many questions on the website here

Comment: Sure. Although it would be beneficial for me if my time is converted to reputation! Hope you understand.